# Как сделать много environments подтягивающиеся с сервера?

Tags: javascript, .net, angular

**Идея:** есть несколько environments и будут новые которые добавляются, надо чтобы с Azure можно было менять свойство конкретного environment и оно подтягивалось сразу в проект в этот environment.
Но как это сделать если свойства environment в angular.json содержат еще дополнительные полезные надстройки (AOT, optimization, ...)?

**Проблема:** каждый раз когда надо добавить новое окружение надо идти создавать новый environment.*name*.ts, потом добавить его в angular.json.

Вот что посоветовали посмотреть, но вопрос с изменениями в angular.json и environment.*name*.ts это не решает.

P.S. Бекенд на .Net

Comment: использовать `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` + `webpack.DefinePlugin` и переменные брать из окружения, в конечном счете тебе не нужно будет дублировать `environment` файлы, а так же дублировать скрипты, чтобы указать `configuration`. У меня на проекте около 30 энвов в разных регионах и зонах доступности внутри регионов, у каждого энва есть свой aws codebuild (я не знаю как называется альтернатива в эйжуре, думаю контейнер сервис). У каждого codebuild есть свой набор энв. переменных для каждого энва, приложение билдится и кладется в бакет, далее сервится через CDN

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - это запросить `environment` до бутстрапа приложения и записать их куда-нибудь.

```
@NgModule({
    // bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
    ngDoBootstrap(app: ApplicationRef) {
        fetch(envUrl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(vars => environment.dynamicVars = vars);
            .then(() => app.bootstrap(AppComponent))
            .catch(console.error)
    }
}
```